# Eclipse Kepler for linux

Tags: android, linux, eclipse

So I have numerous distros of eclipse and enjoy linuxmint but can not seem to get the ADT or Sdk for android to register.I do not use home internet as my phone covers most needs so I am hoping for some offline downloads that may assist me with this problem. My sdk is located in my home dir under its own folder as is the Adt.Do i have to code something in linux?

Comment: Android-Studio is now to recommended for Android development, Eclipse support for ADT is ending soon.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response...I have even attempted the newest studio download for linux n sdk tools but have no luck there either.I have been teaching myself java mainly for android with a few low end free apps but am getting discouraged over these should be easily dissolved problems.The android site walk through involves the host being online but again not possible.I have both studio downloads for linux as well as the sdks and windows.Im a newcomer to linux as well and help with a mint studio setup would be Awesome